# how to encrypt one column of a table without using always encrypted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, encryption, always-encrypted

I have been working on [a solution to synchronise logins (using T-SQL)](http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror) between 2 servers, or between AlwaysOn nodes, inspired by [sqlsoldier](http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/team-view/sqlsoldier).

[It requires a linked Server.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205918/linked-server-issue-while-synchronising-logins-between-servers-using-t-sql)

When run, this procedure outputs the following set of scripts that need to be applied in the current server for synchronising the logins (example):

```
 Create Login [MY_COMPANY_UK\DW_and_Extracts] From Windows; 
 Create Login [MY_COMPANY_UK\AuPairDWETL_TS] From Windows; 
 Exec  sp_addsrvrolemember @rolename = 'sysadmin', @loginame = 'NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER'; 
GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION  To  [MY_COMPANY_UK\RGDLMonitoring]; 
GRANT CONNECT SQL  To  [MY_COMPANY_UK\DW_and_Extracts]; 
GRANT CONNECT SQL  To  [MY_COMPANY_UK\AuPairDWETL_TS]; 
GRANT CONNECT On ENDPOINT::[SSBEndpoint] To [MY_COMPANY_USA\sqlservice];
```

I would like to log all these commands to a table before I apply them to my current server, but I understand these are sensitive information, and I would like to be able to encrypt it and be able to decrypt.

What could I achieve this?

I have already seen this:

[Is It Possible to Encrypt varbinary(max) Column Using Always Encrypted Feature?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-varbinarymax-column-using-always-encrypted-feature)

How could I achieve this, with minimal effort, and not affecting anything else on my systems?

([I currently don't use always encrypted](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4011/sql-server-2016-always-encrypted/))

Comment: There are [powershell scripts](https://dbatools.io/command-search/?search=logins)  available that will sync logins between nodes but I understand you might have other needs that warrant to use tsql. These might help. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/ and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-column-level-encryption-decryption-in-sql-server-2016/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has had column encryption with server-managed keys since SQL 2005.  See [Encrypt a Column of Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017).

AlwaysEncrypted uses client-side keys.